# Is there a way to add custom roads (e.g. off-road routes) to google maps and then get directions to use them?

Tags: api, google-maps, driving-directions, map-directions

I want to add some custom roads using google maps api (i.e. off-road routes, gravel roads that aren't marked as roads in the map, etc) and then use those roads **in conjunction** with existing roads to get directions. I know this isn't possible out of the box, but I wonder if there are any tools, custom implementations or 3rd party libraries to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to do this at this time. You would have to essentially create your own routing application.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I'm interested in any custom implementations, 3rd party libraries and experiences of other who tried to do that. And I don't mind to have my own routing application. But there's no way to access the road data on google maps, is there? So my routing application only could do routes on my custom roads, and that's not enough.